# Bootstrap - Margins causing columns to wrap to next line when using canvas

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am trying to place two charts next to each other with some padding or margins between the columns. I have no issues if the columns contain text but not working with the `canvas` tag. If I place them side-by-side with no margin it works okay, but adding a margin causes the chart to wrap to the next line.

I've tried adding gutters, padding, `container` vs `container-fluid`. Adding `mx-#` will sometimes work but snap to the next line on resize.

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Dataset #1",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    borderWidth: 2,
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    data: [65, 59, 20, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  }]
};

var options = {
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  scales: {
    y: {
      stacked: true,
      grid: {
        display: true,
        color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
      }
    },
    x: {
      grid: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
};

new Chart('bar-chart', {
  type: 'bar',
  options: options,
  data: data
});

new Chart('bar-chart2', {
  type: 'bar',
  options: options,
  data: data
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row p-2 bg-dark ">
    <div class="col-6 bg-white shadow rounded">
      <h3>Col1</h3>
      <canvas id="bar-chart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-white shadow rounded">
      <h3>Col2</h3>
      <canvas id="bar-chart2"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using two col-6, they take up the whole space (12 cols) so adding a margin forces the second to go the next line, i suggest putting your content inside another div inside col-6 with some padding:

```
 .mycanvas {
   padding: 10px;
 }

 <div class="col-6">
  <div class="mycanvas bg-white shadow rounded">
    <h3>Col1</h3>
    <canvas id="bar-chart"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="mycanvas bg-white shadow rounded">
    <h3>Col2</h3>
    <canvas id="bar-chart2"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```